Getting "no jniLLVM in java.library.path" error when using javacpp-preset/llvm
I am trying to use javacpp-presets/llvm but I am getting the error "no jniLLVM in java.library.path". I am using intellij and set the path in the configuration in vm options to

-Djava.library.path="C:\Users<username>.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.bytedeco\llvm-platform\17.0.6-1.5.10"

but I still get the error. I took a look in this directory in the .jar file and there is only a folder named "META-INF" but shouldn't there be more and a file called "jnillvm.dll"?
I am using gradle and added these three dependencies:
implementation("org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:llvm:7.0.1-1.4.4")
implementation("org.bytedeco:llvm-platform:17.0.6-1.5.10")
implementation("org.bytedeco:llvm:17.0.6-1.5.10")

The full error message is:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniLLVM in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:1832)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1423)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1234)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1210)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.LLVM.<clinit>(LLVM.java:10)
    at org.prola.codegeneration.llvm.CodeGenerator2.<init>(CodeGenerator2.kt:10)
    at org.prola.MainKt.main(Main.kt:31)
    at org.prola.MainKt.main(Main.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not find jniLLVM in class, module, and library paths.
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:1799)
    ... 7 more

Had someone this issue before and knows where it comes from?
I tried using an older version but it didn't help. I also thought about downloading the jnillvm.dll manually but I couldn't find where I could download it.

You should drop the org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:llvm dependency, as that is an ancient version.

Secondly, if you look at the pom file for the llvm-platform artifact, you see that it has dependencies to several dependencies with platform-specific classifiers. In your case the DLL should be in org.bytedeco:llvm with classifier windows-x86_64. I don't think you should have to set java.library.path yourself.

Thanks allot for this answer! This helped.

If you managed to figure it out, feel free to post a self-answer with your solution. It might help someone else with the same problem.

The solution is actually pretty simple.
I only added these two dependecies:
implementation("org.bytedeco:llvm-platform:17.0.6-1.5.10")
implementation("org.bytedeco:llvm:17.0.6-1.5.10")

The "jniLLVM.dll" is not in org.bytedeco:llvm-platform, it is in org.bytedeco:llvm. I also removed the "java.library.path", otherwise the error persists.
